# Trouble Scraping Whole chart from HTML

Tags: r, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the entire chart from this website:

http://stats.ncaa.org/team/stats/12021?org_id=749&sport_year_ctl_id=12021

But when I run this code:

```
library(XML)
library(gsubfn)

URL = 'http://stats.ncaa.org/team/stats?org_id=381&sport_year_ctl_id=12021'


Player_Stats = readHTMLTable(URL, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

Player_Stats
```

Player_Stats only returns the data for the players, up until and not including the Total line.

What I want is the Team Totals and Opponent Totals.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That information is in a `<tfoot>` element at the bottom of the table, which is why `readHTMLTable()` isn't picking up on it. You can extract the `<tfoot>` bit separately using `getNodeSet()` as follows.  I've bound the two bits of the table together at the end, but you may want to keep the different kinds of information apart for your application.

```
library(XML)
library(gsubfn)
URL = 'http://stats.ncaa.org/team/stats?org_id=381&sport_year_ctl_id=12021'
Player_Stats = readHTMLTable(URL, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
stats <- Player_Stats$stat_grid

doc <- htmlTreeParse(URL, useInternalNodes=T)
foot <- getNodeSet(doc,"//tfoot")
totals <- readHTMLTable(unlist(foot)[[1]])
colnames(totals) <- colnames(stats)
fulltable <- rbind(stats,totals)
```